# extract specific data from a HTML table or hide specific lines

Tags: javascript, html, external, extract

Please help as this is doing my head in. My scripting skills are basic but I learn quickly.
I have HTML code that runs a java script on an external website and displays a table.
In my case it is a football leagues upcoming fixtures. I want to display this table using the code on our clubs website but I only want it to show certain lines of the table, ie only the matches that include the 2 teams from our club which is Watford Ladies FC.

Is there a way to either modify this script to hide certain lines or another script to extract certain lines and populate into another table?
The code I have to work with is:

```
<div id="lrep509554198" style="width: 350px;">Data loading....<a href="http://full-time.thefa.com/Index.do?divisionseason=511456772">click here for Under 15's Division Two</a><br/><br/><a href="http://www.thefa.com/FULL-TIME">FULL-TIME Home</a></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var lrcode = '509554198'
</script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://full-time.thefa.com/client/api/cs1.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately it requires you to allow unsafe script so it wont generate properly here.
If you copy the code into a HTML file and load into IE, allow scripts, youll see the table.

Many Thanks
Mark

Comment: Can you show the table html which you need to display?

Comment: I cant get the code to render on this post but if you run this code in IE/chrome, it will render the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this script to your html,

```
<div id="lrep509554198" style="width: 350px;">Data loading....<a href="http://full-time.thefa.com/Index.do?divisionseason=511456772">click here for Under 15's Division Two</a><br/><br/><a href="http://www.thefa.com/FULL-TIME">FULL-TIME Home</a></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var lrcode = '509554198'
</script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://full-time.thefa.com/client/api/cs1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load() {
    var trElements = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var trsWithMatch = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < trElements.length; i++) {
        var innerChildr = trElements[i].innerHTML;
        if(innerChildr.indexOf('Watford Ladies Wasps') == -1) {
            trsWithMatch.push(i);
        }
    }
    if(trsWithMatch.length != 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < trsWithMatch.length; i++) {
            var indexFor = trsWithMatch[i];
            var trMatched = trElements[indexFor];
            trMatched.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
window.onload = load;

</script>
```

Comment: You Sir...are a freaking Genius!! Works perfectly and is exactly what Im after. I have spent so many hours trying to code this myself.